# Duda sobre sqlite en java

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

Actualmente estoy realizando mi primer trabajo para un cliente, estoy usando sqlite3 en java.

Bueno la duda es la siguiente, para realizar el proyecto necesito crear una base de datos, y para probar el programa llenó la base de datos con datos ficticios.

Ahora ¿qué pasa cuando le entrego el proyecto a mi cliente?, ¿cómo se crea la base de datos tablas etc.. en su computadora?, y ¿qué pasa con la conexión que hago en la base de datos?.

¿El cliente tiene que instalar algo en la computadora, el tiene que crear su propia base de datos?.

```
public class Conector {
   String url="C:\\Users\\Diego U\\Documents\\Christian Manager";
    Connection connect;

    public void Connect()
    {
        try {
         connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+url);
         if (connect!=null) {
             System.out.println("Conectado");

         }
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
         System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n"+ex.getMessage());
     }
    }

     public void close(){
        try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     }

}
```

Esa es la parte de mi clase que conecta la base de datos con java

Comment: Primero, tu cliente deberá instalar Java en su computadora. Segundo, el cliente deberá tener la base de datos localmente en algún directorio. Por ejemplo, en la carpeta Documentos o en algún sitio. Luego en tu programa estableces la ruta de ese archivo. En tu programa puedes darle la opción al cliente de elegir dónde desea guardar el archivo y guardar esa ruta en la base de datos una vez creada. Cada vez que inicie el programa se comprueba que el archivo existe en la ruta guardada, si no existe, se le presenta un aviso sobre esto. Puedes hacerlo a tu gusto pero, no conozco otra manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías enfocar el problema de la siguiente forma:

1. Primero, crea tú la base de datos vacía (o con los datos absolutamente imprescindibles para que tu aplicación funcione de cero) y se la proporcionas al cliente para que éste la copie allí donde más le apetezca. Delegar esto en el cliente no es buena idea porque es probable que él no tenga ni idea de BD o de la estructura de tablas que tú hayas definido
2. Externaliza el valor que asignas a URL. Puedes ponerlo en un fichero de propiedades que leas al arrancar la aplicación o pasárselo como parámetro en el arranque. Cuando el cliente te diga donde dejará la BD, le configuras la opción que hayas escogido con ese valor y ya lo tendrías resuelto (si fuese como parámetro de arranque, junto al jar y a la BD le das un script de arranque que le "oculte" eso)